# Hypersurface in a Perturbation of Schwarzchild Spacetime

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have a fairly simple question about perturbations of Schwarzchild spacetime in general relativity but cannot seem to find the answer anywhere.

Start with the standard Schwarzchild metric

$g^{SCH}= -\phi^2 dt^2 + \Bigg(1 + \frac{m_0}{2 r} \Bigg)^4 \delta$

where $\delta$ is the Euclidean metric and $\phi$ is defined to be the warping factor

$\phi = \frac{1 - \frac{m_0}{2r} }  {1 + \frac{m_0}{2r}}$

and then add a perturbation so that you have a perturbed metric $g_{\alpha \beta} = g^{SCH}_{\alpha \beta} + h_{\alpha \beta}$, where the size of the components of $h_{\alpha \beta}$ is small (in some suitable sense or norm).  Now if one takes the $t=0$ hypersurface in this perturbed spacetime, what would the induce metric $g_{ij}$ be and what would the extrinsic curvature $k_{ij}$ be?  In the case of regular Schwarzchild, the extrinsic curvature of the $t=0$ hypersurface would vanish due to the spacetime being static, but now it has to take some general form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout, Roman indices run over spacial coordinates while Greek indices run over all coordinates.

Since you're always working in an adapted coordinate system with $\partial_0$ orthogonal to the hypersurface, the induced metric is quite simple: just the restriction of the ambient metric to the spatial coordinates (which is why the notation $g_{ij}$ is justified).

The second fundamental form simplifies similarly in adapted coordinates. In codimension one, we can write the scalar second fundamental form with respect to the future unit normal vector $n$, and expand in terms of Christoffel symbols.
$$
k_{ij}=\left\langle n,\nabla_i\partial_j\right\rangle=\left\langle n,\Gamma^\alpha{}_{ij}\partial_\alpha\right\rangle=\Gamma^\alpha{}_{ij}\langle n,\partial_\alpha\rangle=n^\beta\Gamma_{\beta ij}
$$
For actually computing the normal, one can use the fact that $(dx^0)^\sharp$ is orthogonal to the hypersurface, and only needs to be normalized.
$$
n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g^{00}}}g^{0\alpha}\partial_\alpha
$$
And thus
$$
k_{ij}=\frac{\Gamma^{0}{}_{ij}}{\sqrt{-g^{00}}}
$$
Does it make sense this computation would proceed for your metric?

Comment: Yes, I think the computation makes sense.  For the induced metric I think that was my first impression that would one could take the spacelike Schwarzchild metric and add the spatial components of the perturbation, so one would have $g_{ij} = g^{SCH}_{ij} + h_{i j} $ where $h_{i j}$ are the spatial parts only of $h_{\alpha \beta}$.  I think computing the Christoffel symbols for a perturbed metric is slightly involved, but I have seen it done in a relativity textbook I think.

Comment: Your comment on the induced metric is correct. The Christoffel symbols aren't actually that involved; you can apply the Koszul formula, and with an lowered index this don't even require inverting the metric: $$\Gamma_{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\frac 12 (\partial_\beta g_{\gamma\alpha} + \partial_\gamma g_{\beta\alpha} - \partial_\alpha g_{\beta\gamma}) $$

Comment: Are you sure that formula for the Christoffel symbols is correct.  I've checked the textbook on gravity by Misner-Thorpe-Wheeler and on page 967 for a perturbed metric it has $\Gamma^{\mu}_{ \beta \gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \alpha} (\partial_{\gamma} h_{\alpha \beta} + \partial_{\beta} h_{\alpha \gamma} - \partial_{\alpha} h_{\beta \gamma})$ where $g^{\mu \nu}$ is the inverted perturbed metric and $h$ is the perturbation.  This is for a spacetime however, rather than a spacelike hypersurface.

Comment: The Christoffel symbol for the perturbed spacetime $\Gamma_{0 i j}$ has to incorporate the perturbation, otherwise for standard Schwarzchild spacetime $\Gamma_{0 i j} = 0$, which takes us back to $k_{i j} = 0$ for the spacelike Schwarzchild metric.

Comment: The computation above is done in the ambient manifold, and$\Gamma_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ refers to the christoffel symbol of the ambient manifold, so we can freely raise/lower indices with the ambient metric and its inverse. You're correct that without the perturbation, $\Gamma_{0ij}=0$, since, as you say, the umperturbed $t=0$ slice has no extrinsic curvature. If you compute the same symbol for $h_{\alpha\beta}\neq 0$, however, some terms will show up.

Comment: For the case of Christoffel symbols for a perturbed spacetime metric, Misner has $\Gamma^{\mu}_{\beta \gamma} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \alpha}(\partial_{\gamma} h_{\alpha \beta} + \partial_{\beta} h_{\alpha \gamma} - \partial_{\alpha} h_{\beta \gamma})$.  For the Christoffel symbol of the hypersurface, I assume one can take the same Christoffel symbol but sums only over the Roman indices?

Comment: In adapted coordinates, the Christoffel symbol of the hypersurface is related in a more complicated way, derived by $\widetilde{\nabla}_XY=\pi(\nabla_XY)$ where $\widetilde{\nabla}$ is the connection on the hypersurface, $\nabla$ is the ambient connection, and $\pi$ is the orthogonal projection. That said, for computing $k$ there's no need to compute the Christoffel symbol of the hypersurface; all the computations are done in the ambient manifold.

Comment: For computing $k$ one can do the computations on the ambient manifold, but I think I might need to consider the Dirac equation for the spacelike hypersurface: in that equation the spin connection is given by $e_i + \frac{1}{4} \Sigma_{j,l=1}^3 \Gamma_{i j}^{l} c(e_j) c(e_l)$, so in this case I take it one actually needs the Christoffel symbol for the hypersurface as the indices only go from $1$ to $3$.

Comment: I just realized that your perturbation is such that the form of $n$ is in general a bit more complicated, and amended the answer accordingly. As for computing the Christoffel symbols, the above identity works out to $\widetilde{\Gamma}^i{}_{jk}=(\delta^i_\alpha+n^in_\alpha)\Gamma^\alpha{}_{ij}$, where $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ is the hypersurface Christoffel symbol.

Comment: In terms of inverting a metric, one can normally find the matrix representation for the inverse metric using the fact that $g^{i j} g_{j k} = \delta^i_k$.  As this is a spacetime does one instead have $g^{\mu \sigma} g_{\sigma \nu} = \eta^{\mu}_{\nu}$, which implies that $g^{0 0} = 1/\phi^2$ since $g_{0 0} = -\phi^2$ (assuming signature $(-,+,+,+)$)?

Comment: Ah no, it has to be $g^{0 0 } = -1/\phi^2$, otherwise the normal vector has an imaginary number when you normalize it.

Comment: $g^{00}=-\phi^{-2}$ absent a perturbation, but in general $g^{00}$ will depend (in a somewhat complicated way) on $h$, which was the oversight before. The correct definition of the inverse metric is $g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\beta\gamma}=\delta^\alpha_\gamma$.